# Image upload internal server error 500 only for iphone

Tags: php, objective-c

The image is getting uploaded from android to server but the image is not getting uploaded from iphone to server. I am getting internal server error for iphone even i cant upload 2kb file too.

Comment: Have you checked your logs to see what the error is? Is this with Apache or another server?

Comment: It apache only and when i upload from the android its working and getting response when i used to upload from iphone only the internal server error is getting.

Comment: What is the real error though? Internal server error is just the public message that something has gone wrong. It would be logged in your Apache error logs (or if you have them disabled, you should enable them.)

Comment: [client 182.65.169.228] File does not exist: /home/commonwe/public_html/500.shtml has been displayed in the error log but the file is there

Comment: Need your code to examine the issue.

Comment: $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["fishImage"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {

Comment: if ($_FILES["fishImage"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["fishImage"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
  
    if (file_exists("../fish_catches_img/" . $_FILES["fishImage"]["name"]))
      {
   $mytime=time();
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fishImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "../fish_catches_img/$mytime" . $_FILES["fishImage"]["name"]);
  $filename="$mytime". $_FILES["fishImage"]["name"];
    
      }

Comment: else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fishImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "../fish_catches_img/" . $_FILES["fishImage"]["name"]);
  $filename= $_FILES["fishImage"]["name"];
   
      }
    }
  }

Comment: The above code has been used in my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the image uploading type to base 64 i.e, I asked iphone developers to encode the stream of bytes with base 64 and then I handled with base 64 decode and storing the file. It worked in the emulator but while using in the iphone it showed page not found error and then we compressed the image size by decreasing the image resolution and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web server access log and error log files to identify the specific error.

Comment: [client 182.65.169.228] File does not exist: /home/commonwe/public_html/500.shtml has been displayed in the error log but the file is there

Comment: that 500.shtml is basically the 500 internal server error page. Are you using .htaccess files for this page/folder on your webserver. Looks to be a conf issue with .htaccess. It might be configured to disable requests coming from specific user-agents like iphone etc. Pls post the .htaccess file here

Comment: DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/front/(.+)$ /front/$2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/img/(.+)$ /img/$2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z/0-9_]+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
</ifModule>

ErrorDocument 403 /error
ErrorDocument 404 /error  oly this code has been wrote in .htaccess file this is my client server and i havent used any htaccess file for my page folder

Answer (score 0):

Check your file path properly. May be issue raise because of that.